# text should always be inside an image box

Tags: html, css

I have an box which is an image and I have text inside the image which will be geenrated dynamically.

Please look at the attached screenshot for more information.

How do I make sure that the image stretches when there is more text ?

[image]

```
.my-community-box{
        background: url('/assets/my-community-box.png') no-repeat !important;
        background-size: 100%;
        width: 287px;
        min-height: 474px;
        float: right;

        .my-community-details{
            background-color: @mild-gray;
            margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
            padding: 5px;

            ul{
                width: 250px;
                margin: 0 0 9px 0;
                li{

                }
            }

            a{
                color: @darker-green;
            }

            a:hover{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: @light-green;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use a border, not an image. Otherwise you will need to sprite the image.

Comment: Please give us some code, so we know what we are dealing with

Comment: hi @Dev R u want to this http://tinkerbin.com/4Cv1rWEA

Comment: updated the question with code

Comment: @RohitAzad yes but with image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a border?

```
.my-community-box{
        background: #F3F3F2;
        width: 287px;
        min-height: 474px;
        float: right;
        border: 3px solid #C5C3C3;
}

.my-community-box-wrap{
        border-left: 2px solid #C2E2A0;
        border-right: 2px solid #C2E2A0;
        float: right;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AWXHr/

Comment: there is a greenish ting outside the border how will I get that and is it not possible to do what I am trying to do with images ?

Comment: Edited for the green border: Put another div around your community box div for the green borders

Comment: can this be achieved with images ?

Comment: Yes but it would make your load times longer so we recommend against it.

Comment: I want to do it with image can you please provide a solution for that

Comment: The problem with images is that you can't stretch them you can repeat them but that would repeat the border too. So if you were able to do it with an image it would be a lot of work for a bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to `background-repeat: repeat-y;` the image, but will have to change it. as far as it seems, it is one single image - you will have to crop it to have the top border and the "body" of the image will be the part that you want to vertical repeat.

alternatively, due to the simple design, you could just use css `borders`

EDIT
also, as a few comments suggested, you should show us some code and not just an image, that would help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use css border instead of image

```
  div{
    border:#333 solid 6px; border-radius:0 0 6px 6px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2pt green;   
    height:auto;
    width:200px;
    background:#c1c1c1
}​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/wYUFD/12/

Comment: there is a greenish ting outside the border how will I get that and is it not possible to do what I am trying to do with images ?

Comment: @Vlakarados look at the image which I have attached and you will notice the greenish tinge

Comment: He means the green border in the example

Comment: box-shadow is not supported everywhere so recommending it would not be a good idea.

Comment: @RJD22 Who told that there is not any ways to achieve?? Check this http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/10/css3-rounded-corners-for-ie-6-7-8.html

Comment: Sowmya: Well ofcourse you can do it with Javascript but those are the solutions you want to avoid as a developer. Since styling your site with javascript is usually seen as a bad idea

Comment: javascript?? there is no script involved in that. behavior is css property

Answer (score 1):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/6CxmJ6gD)***

Hi now used to `background-size:cover;` or `max-width`

as like this

```
p{
 max-width:200px;
  border:solid 10px red;
  background:url('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/eb71f65106648cf6618b10423e8b0451?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  color:#fff;
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/6CxmJ6gD)***

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may be helpful to you

```
.my-community-details{
        background-color: @mild-gray;
        margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        max-width: //set what depends up on your image width
        max-height: //set what depends up on your image height
        overflow-y: auto;
```